# Can not save multiple pictures Json in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, carrierwave

I want to add multiple pictures to each renter model but I can not save them on my renter controller.
I have used the gem Carrierwave to upload them.

controllers/renters_controller.rb

```
def create
 @renter = Renter.new(renter_params)

 if @renter.save
   gflash notice: "Le loueur a bien été enregistré"
   redirect_to '/'
 else
   gflash :now, notice: "Une erreur est survenue."
   render :new
 end
end

def renter_params
  params.require(:renter).permit(:name, :address, :website, :email, :phone, :review, :latitude, :longitude, :user_id, pictures: [])
end
```

models/renter.rb

```
class Renter < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  geocoded_by :address
  after_validation :geocode
  reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude
  after_validation :reverse_geocode  # auto-fetch address
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  mount_uploader :pictures; PicturesUploader
end
```

I have an uploader file
uploaders/pictures_uploader.rb

and on my view form
views/renters/_form.html.haml

```
= form_for(@renter, :hmtl => {:multipart => true}) do |f|
  - if @renter.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2
        = pluralize(@renter.errors.count, "error")
        prohibited this renter from being saved:
      %ul
        - @renter.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
          %li= message

  .row
    .large-6.medium-6.columns
      = f.text_field :name, placeholder: t('.name')
    .large-6.medium-6.columns
      = f.text_field :website, placeholder: t('.website')
  .row
    .large-6.medium-6.columns
      = f.text_field :email, placeholder: t('.email')
    .large-6.medium-6.columns
      = f.text_field :phone, placeholder: t('.phone')
  .row
    .large-6.medium-6.columns
      = f.text_field :address, placeholder: t('.address')
    .large-3.medium-3.columns
      = f.text_field :latitude, placeholder: :latitude
    .large-3.medium-3.columns
      = f.text_field :longitude, placeholder: :longitude
  .row
    = f.file_field :pictures, multiple: true, accept: "image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/gif, image/png"


  .row
    .large-12.columns.large-centered
      .large-12.columns.large-centered
      = f.submit :value => 'Valider', :class => 'default button'
```

and my errors message

```
Processing by RentersController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"3YfZtWpnDb03yRs1HVp11jJSE15mm6PLOyIKxeJTcoOWsBaFNR/LYYYkD921Zzy5Urb9wgV5tpyhwG8oVAvZPw==", "renter"=>{"name"=>"Miami boat rental", "website"=>"", "email"=>"", "phone"=>"", "address"=>"", "latitude"=>"", "longitude"=>"", "pictures"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f8ab9728530 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/1d/5fhghxdx5hz_7clwv4gkbwm80000gn/T/RackMultipart20160225-2432-sy0x2h.png>, @original_filename="corse_catamarans.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"renter[pictures][]\"; filename=\"corse_catamarans.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">]}, "commit"=>"Valider"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):
app/controllers/renters_controller.rb:43:in `create'
```

I think that the problem is due to the json of the pictures, but it is just my feeling. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the uploader only for pictures, but your are requiring 'image' param, you cannot leave this param to `nil`.

```
params.require(:renter).permit(:name, :address, :website, :email, :phone, :review, :latitude, :longitude, :user_id, :image, pictures: [])
```

You should remove this param from the strong parameters method. Like this :

```
params.require(:renter).permit(:name, :address, :website, :email, :phone, :review, :latitude, :longitude, :user_id, pictures: [])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just changed it, but I still have the same error.

Comment: Can you post views/renters/_form.html.haml views with the complete form ? and the callback methods in Renter model?